# Change url according to screen orientation

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have created a website in WordPress and would like the contact page to appear whenever the smartphone is placed in landscape position from any page.
I would also need the smartphone to return to the page I was on before I turned it to portrait position.

I have tried the following code, but when I put the smartphone back in portrait it always takes me back to the homepage.

```
let landscape = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");

landscape.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if(e.matches) {
        window.location.href = "https://website.com/contacts/";
    } else {      
        window.history.back();
    }
})
```

Can you help me understand what's wrong, please?

Thank you!

**EDIT: I re-did some tests and found that the code does not always take me to the homepage, but back two pages instead of one**

Comment: Are you sure `window.history.back(-1)` goes back one page? The correct syntax is `window.history.back()` or `window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm sorry, I pasted the wrong code. I tried both your syntax but goes back to homepage not only one page.

Comment: Try to console.log in your function to see if it gets called multiple times

Answer (score 1):

What an interesting behavior. I'm wondering what it is for...

You should just listen for the orientation itself. You can use [`screen.orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation), tho it is not supported by Safari nor Safari on iOS.

For Safari IOS we can use the deprecated (but not for Safari IOS) `orientationchange`.

```
/**
 * Redirect on orientation change.
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(screen.orientation.type === 'landscape-primary' || screen.orientation.type === 'landscape-secondary') {
        window.location = "https://website.com/contacts/";
    };
});

/**
 * Redirect on orientation change (Support for Safari IOS).
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|iphone/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/safari/i)) {
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        if(window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {  
            window.location = "https://website.com/contacts/";
        };
    });
};
```